# Problem with sending image capture from camera pi over UDPSocket

Tags: python, camera, serversocket

I want to send capture image from camera Pi over UDPSocket. I'm using sendto function. But it keep getting 'TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not tuple' although i have change the images to bytes type. Here is my code so far:

```py
import io
import time
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import numpy as np
import cv2
import socket,traceback
host=""
port = 5555
    #socketsever create
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
print("socket create")
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)
s.bind((host,port))
print("bind success")
camera=PiCamera()
camera.resolution=(640,480)
capture=PiRGBArray(camera,size=(640,480))
while(1):
    message,add=s.recvfrom(1024)
    print(message)
    camera.capture(capture,format='bgr')
    capture.seek(0)
    image_bytes=capture.array
    image_bytes=cv2.imencode('.jpg',image_bytes)[1].tostring()

    print(type(image_bytes))
    s.sendto(image_bytes,(add,port))
    capture.seek(0)
    capture.truncate(0)
```

this is the result :

```
socket create
bind success
b'hello'
<class 'bytes'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera1.py", line 31, in <module>
    s.sendto(image_bytes,(add,port))
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not tuple
```

Help me please

Comment: Never worked on sockets but seems like imencode returns a tuple with retval and buffer. However, sendto is expecting a string. Can you try ```s.sendto(image_bytes[1], (add,port))``` but again buffer here could be a list. Please check if you are passing string

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have try ```s.sendto(image_bytes[1], (add,port))``` and it return an int, so buffer maybe is a list and I have check again and sendto() expecting a byte - like objects. Do you know how can i convert the buffer to string and the to byte - like object?

Comment: Try `bytearray(image_bytes))`.